# NameError: name ‘workshop’ is not defined

Tags: python

me parece el error NameError: name ‘workshop’ is not defined

código:

```
def all_reports(app,workshop):
    reportes=[]
    # print(session)
    print(workshop)
    for i in workshop:
        if i['type'] == 'Workspace':
            url=f"https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{i['id']}/reports"
            api_response = requests.get(url, headers=get_request_header(app))
    if api_response.status_code != 200:
        abort(api_response.status_code, description=f'Error while retrieving Embed URL\n{api_response.reason}:\t{api_response.text}\nRequestId:\t{api_response.headers.get("RequestId")}')
    api_response = json.loads(api_response.text)
    for a in api_response['value']:
        dic2={'id_workshop':i['id'],'id_report':a['id'], 'name_report':a['name'] }
    reportes.append(dic2)
    print(dic2)

@app.route('/allworkshop')
def reporte():
     return all_reports(app,workshop)
```

Donde debo definir el parámetro workshop? el error lo marca en la ultima línea.

Anteriormente a este código ya tengo definida la def get_access_token(app), def get_request_header(app) y def all_workshop2(app)

```
def all_workshop2(app):
    url='https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups'
    api_response = requests.get(url, headers=get_request_header(app))
    if api_response.status_code != 200:
        abort(api_response.status_code, description=f'Error while retrieving Embed URL\n{api_response.reason}:\t{api_response.text}\nRequestId:\t{api_response.headers.get("RequestId")}')
    api_response = json.loads(api_response.text)
    print(api_response)
    api_response['value']

    return (api_response['value'])
```

En def all_reports(app,workshop) el workshop me vendría dado por el anterior código pero no se como pasarlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo leer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/get-reports donde indica que `groupId` se refiere al identificador del área de trabajo donde lo especificas como un diccionario para ser usado en la url de petición `{i['id']}`. Para esto, **`power-bi`** te proporciona diferentes opciones, como consultar reportes, grupos de usuario, etc... Los cuales puedes consultarlos usando funciones separadas, por ejemplo si quieres consultar los grupos, entonces podrías definir una función `get_groups` en la cual haces la petición con la url correspondida y lo demás, en el caso de los reportes he llamado `all_reports` la cual necesitar declarar diferentes variables: `application_id`, `application_key`, `user_id`, `user_password`, `group_id`, `report_id`.

Si quieres crear un diccionario para guardar el `token` de acceso que usarías en `"https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/TOKEN/reports"` entonces debes llamar `get_access_token` para almacenar estos en un arreglo de diccionarios así `workshop['id']`.

```
workshops = list()

for i in range(100):
    workshop = dict()
    workshop['type'] = 'Workspace'
    workshop['id'] = get_access_token(application_id, application_key, user_id, user_password, group_id, report_id)
    workshops.append(workshop)
```

De esta forma podrás implementar como funciones para cada una de las [Operaciones](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports#operations).

```py
APPLICATION_ID = "abcdef-abcdef-abcdef-abcdef" 
APPLICATION_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" 
USER_ID = "example@company.com" 
USER_PASSWORD = "password"  
GROUP_ID = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'  
REPORT_ID = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

def get_access_token(application_id, application_key, user_id, user_password):
    data = {
        'grant_type': 'password',
        'scope': 'openid',
        'resource': "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api",
        'client_id': application_id,
        'client_secret': application_key,
        'username': user_id,
        'password': user_password
    }

    token = requests.post("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token", data=data)

    return token.json()['access_token']

def get_headers(application_id, application_key, user_id, user_password):
    return {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'Authorization': "Bearer {}".format(get_access_token(application_id, application_key, user_id, user_password))
    }

def all_reports(application_id, application_key, user_id, user_password, group_id):
    print(workshop)
    for i in workshop:
        if i['type'] == 'Workspace':
            endpoint = "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{}/reports".format(group_id)
            api_response = requests.get(url, headers=get_headers(application_id, application_key, user_id, user_password))
    if api_response.status_code != 200:
        abort(api_response.status_code, description=f'Error while retrieving Embed URL\n{api_response.reason}:\t{api_response.text}\nRequestId:\t{api_response.headers.get("RequestId")}')
    api_response = json.loads(api_response.text)
    for a in api_response['value']:
        dic2={'id_workshop':i['id'],'id_report':a['id'], 'name_report':a['name'] }
    reportes.append(dic2)
    print(dic2)
    return requests.get(endpoint, headers=headers).json()

@app.route('/allworkshop')
def reporte():
    return all_reports(APPLICATION_ID, APPLICATION_KEY, USER_ID, USER_PASSWORD, GROUP_ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

El error `"NameError: name 'workshop' is not defined"` indica que la variable **workshop** no ha sido definida en el ámbito donde se está utilizando.
En tu código, **workshop** se pasa como argumento en la función **all_reports**, por lo que debes asegurarte de pasar el valor adecuado al llamar a esta función.

En la última línea de tu código, estás llamando a la función **all_reports(app, workshop)**, pero no se muestra dónde se está definiendo o proporcionando el valor para **workshop**. Puedes solucionar esto asegurándote de proporcionar un valor para **workshop** al llamar a la función.

Por ejemplo, si tienes una lista de talleres llamada **workshop** que deseas pasar como argumento, puedes asegurarte de tener esa lista definida antes de llamar a la función. Aquí hay un ejemplo de cómo podrías hacerlo:

```
workshop = [...]  # Definir la lista de talleres aquí

@app.route('/allworkshop')
def reporte():
    return all_reports(app, workshop)
```

Asegúrate de reemplazar [...] con la lista real de talleres que deseas pasar a la función **all_reports**.
De esta manera, la variable **workshop** estará definida y se pasará correctamente a la función.